# Асинхронность в php

Tags: php, многопоточность

друзья! У меня реализовано пару парсеров, который проходят капчу и тянут информацию, что занимает очень много времени. Особенно, если на сайте Рекапча от гугл. Возникает острая проблема в быстродействии скрипта. Возможно как-то запустить каждый парсер в своём потоке? либо как-то асинхронно к ним обращаться.

Comment: запускающий скрипт должен иметь связь с потоками?

Comment: @sterx это не имеет значения. Цель - любой ценой выполнить скрипт быстрее

Comment: ну тогда запускай каждый процесс в цикле вот так
passthru('(php -f /pat/process.php params & ) >> /dev/null 2>&1');
только контролируй их количество через бд или еще как нибудь

Comment: @sterx подводные камни есть?

Comment: если ты не будешь контролировать процессы, теоретически они повесят сервер

Comment: Проще будет использовать очередь задач вроде Gearman, создать все задачи, запустить сколько нужно рабочих процессов и отдать ему их обрабатывать. Это можно сделать и в Laravel в том числе с помощью очередей и задач.